Chocolatey installation problemns on VirtualBox
I'm trying to install Chocolatey on a Win10 machine on VB, but, whene executing this command:
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

I Get:

Forcing web requests to allow TLS v1.2 (Required for requests to Chocolatey.org)                                        Getting latest version of the Chocolatey package for download.                                                          Not using proxy.                                                                                                        Getting Chocolatey from https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/2.3.0.                               Downloading https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/2.3.0 to C:\Users\tiarusky\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocoInstall\chocolatey.zip                                                                                     Not using proxy.                                                                                                        Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish       trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."                                                                     At line:258 char:5                                                                                                      +     (Get-Downloader $url @ProxyConfiguration).DownloadFile($url, $fil ...                                             +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException                                               + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException                                                                                                                                                                                                      Extracting C:\Users\tiarusky\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocoInstall\chocolatey.zip to C:\Users\tiarusky\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocoInstall                                                                                          Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive : The path                                                                  'C:\Users\tiarusky\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocoInstall\chocolatey.zip' either does not exist or is not a valid   file system path.                                                                                                       At line:527 char:5                                                                                                      +     Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive -Path $file -Destinat ...                                             +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Users\tiarus...\chocolatey.zip:String) [Expand-Archive], InvalidOpe     rationException                                                                                                          + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArchiveCmdletPathNotFound,Expand-Archive                                                                                                                                                                          Installing Chocolatey on the local machine                                                                              & : The term 'C:\Users\tiarusky\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocoInstall\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1' is not          recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if   a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.                                                     At line:538 char:3                                                                                                      + & $chocoInstallPS1                                                                                                    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\tiarus...ateyInstall.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException                                                                                                                                                                                          Ensuring Chocolatey commands are on the path                                                                            Ensuring chocolatey.nupkg is in the lib folder

I tried on my real win10 host and it works fine. I also tried various things, as enabling only TLS12, disabling TLS3 and so on, but nothing changed.
Did someone encounter the same problem?

There was a certificate rotation recently that is unlikely to but possibly have some effect - have you tried this? https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/usage/proxy-settings-for-chocolatey/#troubleshooting-installation

No, I haven't. So, i'm assuming virtualbox is acting as proxy ? if so, what location should I set? Tsm, by the way

For what it's worth, the proxy may not be relevant to that specific FAQ - I was more meaning just if your OS doesn't have an up-to-date trusted root cert (or path to the one Chocolatey uses), it may present like that (and that was the first FAQ I found covering it).

I added the cert. Still not working

All works fine by just changing the network option of the VM from NAT to bridged NAT.
